# How to replace properties files by yml files in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Is there anything special to say to Springboot to take in account as configuration yaml files instead the properties files? I'm using Maven and Springboot in a project, if I place the file application.properties in the resources file the configuration is automatically recognised by Springboot.

However just replacing the properties file by a yml file does not work, the file is not taking in account anymore.

Anything to add to splicitely say to SpringBoot to use the yml files?

Below both files:

application.properties:

```
# THYMELEAF (ThymeleafAutoConfiguration)
spring.thymeleaf.check-template-location=true
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=/WEB-INF/views/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
spring.thymeleaf.mode=LEGACYHTML5
spring.thymeleaf.encoding=UTF-8
spring.thymeleaf.content-type=text/html
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
```

and application.yml

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: ${dario.environment:dev}
  thymeleaf:
    check-template-location: true
    thymeleaf.prefix: /WEB-INF/views/
    thymeleaf.suffix: .html
    thymeleaf.mode: LEGACYHTML5
    spring.thymeleaf.encoding: UTF-8
    spring.thymeleaf.content-type: text/html
    cache: false
```

Comment: Hey, how did you write active: ${dario.environment:dev} in your yml file? Where is your yml file reading this from?

Comment: A system property, i.e from the command line -Ddario.environment=prod, if I specify no property, dev will be taken by default. Hope this helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you refer to the section 'Using YAML instead of Properties' in the Spring Boot reference documentation, it says that Spring Boot should pick it up automatically given you have the SnakeYAML library on your classpath.

Having that said, it also states

> If you use ‘starter POMs’ SnakeYAML will be automatically provided via
>   spring-boot-starter

Comment: Thanks, I have SnakeYAML on the classpath, I've just found the problem. THe format of my YML file was not correct. I was repeting the word thymeleaf. Fixed :)